Salesforceのアプリ内および web のメッセージングのイベントリスナーが効かない
アプリ内およびwebのメッセージング機能をテストしています。
会話機能はちゃんと動きましたが、
onEmbeddedMessagingConversationClosed（会話終了時）、onEmbeddedMessagingWindowMinimized（会話ウィンドウズが最小化時）イベント関数はテスト失敗しました。イベント関数がトリガーされないです。
onEmbeddedMessagingReadyイベントだけはトリガーされました。
下記は機能初期化コードの抜粋です、書き方など間違いがないでしょうか
確認していただけると、助かります。
function initEmbeddedMessaging() {
    try {
        embeddedservice_bootstrap.settings.language = 'ja'; 
        window.addEventListener("onEmbeddedMessagingReady", (event) => {
          console.log("Received the onEmbeddedMessagingReady event…");
          embeddedservice_bootstrap.prechatAPI.setHiddenPrechatFields({ "ms_chatParam" : "{!chatParam}"});
        });

        window.addEventListener("onEmbeddedMessagingWindowMinimized", (event) => {
          console.log("Received the onEmbeddedMessagingWindowMinimized event…");
        });            
    
        embeddedservice_bootstrap.init(
            '00DIp0000008i5W',
            'MIAWtt',
            'https://xxxx.sandbox.my.site.com/ESWMIAW1721365462849',
            {
                scrt2URL: 'https://xxxx.sandbox.my.salesforce-scrt.com'
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error loading Embedded Messaging: ', err);
    }
};

